# Android - Define build variance specific config

Tags: android, gradle

Let's say I have 2 build types and 2 flavors

```
buildTypes {
    debug { 
      buildConfigField("String", apiUrl, debugURL)
      ...
    }
    release { ... }
}

flavorDimensions "type"
productFlavors {
     type1 { ... }
     type2 { ... }
}
```

For every one of those types, I can define specific `buildConfigField`. Based on this configuration I'll have 4 build variances `[type1Debug, type1Release, type2Debug, type2Release]`

My question is if I can declare the configuration for specific build variance like `type1Release` or `type2Release`

For example I would like to have something like this:

```
   type1Release {
      buildConfigField("String", apiUrl, type1ReleaseURL)
   }
   type2Release {
      buildConfigField("String", apiUrl, type1ReleaseURL)
   }
   ....
```

Comment: Please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355650/define-buildconfigfield-for-an-specific-flavor-and-buildtype/30486355

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted, Thanks!