# signingConfig has to be different per flavor and build type

Tags: android, gradle

I have two different applications in the same Android Studio project. I have two flavor 'flavor1' and 'flavor2' with three different build types 'staging', 'debug' and 'release'

The problem is that I need to use a different key store per each application.

Now I have this, but it only sign with the same key store.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        def Properties props = new Properties()
        def propFile = new File('./signing.properties')
        if (propFile.canRead()) {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

            if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE')
                    && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD')
                    && props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS')
                    && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
                android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props.getProperty('STORE_FILE'))
                android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props.getProperty('STORE_PASSWORD')
                android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props.getProperty('KEY_ALIAS')
                android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props.getProperty('KEY_PASSWORD')
            } else {
                println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
                android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
            }
        } else {
            println 'signing.properties not found'
            android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
        }
    }
} 

buildTypes {
    staging {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.debug
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need all those prefixes `android.signingConfigs.`

Comment: yeah! I know But, how I can sign each flavor apk with a different key store for the release build type??

Comment: in `signingConfigs`, you define a number of configurations. Then, in `productFlavors`, for each flavor, you can define a specific config to use for signing. I don't know how this interacts with the fact that you also define signingConfig for buildTypes, though. I don't think flavors are designed to have different signatures. Also, since buildTypes have the same package name for a given flavor, I am not sure that's a good idea

Answer (score 6):

You can create flavor specific signing configs:

An example:

```
   signingConfigs {
        flavor1Release {
            storeFile file('home/keys/flavor1keystore.keystore')
            storePassword 'keystorePassword'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'aliasPassword'
        }
        flavor2Release {
            storeFile file('home/keys/flavor2keystore.keystore')
            storePassword 'keystorePassword2'
            keyAlias 'alias2'
            keyPassword 'aliasPassword2'
        }
   }
```

And then in your flavor, select the correct signing config:

```
  productFlavors {
        def flavor1SigningVariable = signingConfigs.flavor1Release
        def flavor2SigningVariable = signingConfigs.flavor2Release

        flavor1 {
            signingConfig flavor1SigningVariable
        }
        flavor2 {
            signingConfig flavor2SigningVariable
        }
 }
```

Comment: Will this code generate signed apk for debug as well? What if I want signed apk only if build type is release? @biddulph.r

Comment: @Ashwin, did u figure out how to do it for release only ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille simply do NOT add any signingconfigs under buildTypes { 
debug { ... } } and your gradle will only sign release flavors with the corresponding signingconfigs.

Comment: @Ashwin if we do that, then what will gradle sign debug flavors with?

Comment: @AbhishekJain debug product-flavors will be signed with the default android debug key. If you want to sign debug product-flavors with different keys then check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222229/debug-signing-config-on-gradle-product-flavors