# android set signingConfigs of productFlavors per buildTypes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My current configuration looks like this:

```
signingConfigs {
        alpha_beta {
            storeFile xx
            storePassword xx
            keyAlias xx
            keyPassword xx
        }
        release1 {
            storeFile xx
            storePassword xx
            keyAlias xx
            keyPassword xx
        }
        release2 {
            storeFile xx
            storePassword xx
            keyAlias xx
            keyPassword xx
        }
}
```

with different flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    flavorWhite {
    }

    flavorBlack {
    }
}
```

and different buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.alpha_beta
    }

    release {
        ...
    }
}
```

My objective now is, for the **RELEASE** build, I want to sign ***flavorWhite*** with ***signingConfigs.release1***, and ***flavorBlack*** with ***signingConfigs.release2***.

I tried everything I can think of and anything I could find online, including 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/3L8I1K_mjuo, [Multiple signingConfigs for multiple variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742184/multiple-signingconfigs-for-multiple-variants) and many others.

Anything I'm missing? thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that you can do what you're asking. My recommendation is to do this instead:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.alpha_beta
    }

    release1 {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release1
    }

    release2 {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release2
    }
}
```

This will give you the following build variants:

- `flavorWhiteDebug`
- `flavorWhiteRelease1`
- `flavorWhiteRelease2`
- `flavorBlackDebug`
- `flavorBlackRelease1`
- `flavorBlackRelease2`

You can then include a `variantFilter` to get rid of the variants you don't want (i.e. `flavorWhiteRelease2` and `flavorBlackRelease1`:

```
variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.flavors*.name.contains("flavorWhite")) {
        setIgnore(variant.buildType.name == "release2")
    } else if (variant.flavors*.name.contains("flavorBlack")) {
        setIgnore(variant.buildType.name == "release1")
    }
}
```

With this in place, your build variants will be:

- `flavorWhiteDebug`
- `flavorWhiteRelease1`
- `flavorBlackDebug`
- `flavorBlackRelease2`