# Different signingConfig in multi-dimensional build flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors, android-flavors, apk-signing

**Small example will describe the case:**

```
flavorDimensions 'shape', 'api'

productFlavors {
        fruit {
             dimension "shape"
        }

        vegtable {
             dimension "shape"
        }

        production {
             dimension "api"
        }

        development {
             dimension "api"
        }
}
```

**Task:**
I need to keep different signing config for **fruitProduction** and **fruitDevelopment** flavors.

I have researched the gradle doc and I have not found the suitable task where I can override the config for special flavor.

Comment: [Answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742184/multiple-signingconfigs-for-multiple-variants) may help you.