# Multiple signingConfigs + flavor + buildType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have several flavors, buildtypes and siginiConfig and everything is ready, but it never catches the sigini flavor.
It always takes siginiConfig from buildType.

I already checked all the documentation I found and I just saw examples that the buildtype did not have sigini, there are no examples of buildtypes and flavors with sigini.

```
signingConfigs {
        A {
            storeFile file(./keystore/a.jks)
            storePassword 'asws5478'
            keyAlias 'app_a'
            keyPassword 'asws5478'
        }
        B {
            storeFile file(./keystore/b.jks)
            storePassword 'sffer555'
            keyAlias 'app_b'
            keyPassword 'sffer555'
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true           
            signingConfig signingConfigs.A
        }
        homolog {
            debuggable true           
            useProguard false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.A
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false           
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.A
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    productFlavors {
        generic {...
        }
        clientMajor {
            minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.B
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing product flavors with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040494/signing-product-flavors-with-gradle)

Comment: did not work, it keeps getting the signature of the buildtypes

Comment: `buildTypes` must come after `productFlavors`... while there are comments confirming that it works.

Comment: [Answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742184/multiple-signingconfigs-for-multiple-variants) may help you.